# Git, push commits one more time with different line endings

Tags: git, push, line-endings

I had accidentally pushed my commits with wrong line endings (CRLF instead LF) . Is it possible to roll it back and send once more with right line endings. Because pull request is a mess now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can amend the last commit by running `git commit --amend` instead of `git commit`. This will not create a new commit but add the staged changes to the last commit.

Note that this will *rewrite* the previous commit, resulting in the same effect as when rebasing. The resulting Git commit object will be different than the previous one, and everyone who depends on that object will have problems. – In general, you shouldn’t rewrite commits once they have been published.

In your case though, as you are making a pull request, you can do it, and it’s also often expected to improve your commits by rebasing until they are accepted in the pull request.

Comment: I don't know why, but I had to make `pull` first before I could push `commit --amend` . Any way it looks like for git even a line ending is a file change so I can commit my files like normal change even if it is only a EOL chage. Thanks for showing the right way.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem where I created a pull request for a Windows-based repo and my gitconfig had `autocrlf` set to false `false` rather than `true`. I had to fix line endings for *multiple* commits. Here's how I did the fix:

1. Set `autocrlf` back to true: `git config --global core.autocrlf true`
2. Interactive rebase: `git rebase -i <endCommit>`. For endCommit, use the hash/reference of the commit one past the last commit to be fixed.
3. When rebase prompts for the commands, specify `edit` for each one.
4. When rebase pauses for each edit, use `git reset head~`, `git add .`, `git commit -m <comment>`, `git rebase --continue`. This reapplies the commit with the corrected line endings.
5. Last, force push the updated branch: `git push origin <branchName> -f`

This was tedious, and I'd be interested in knowing if someone knows an easier way to do this.

Comment: When I install Git for Windows, I believe there was an option to check out with CRLF and check in with LF. But in either case, I have `autocrlf = true` and `safecrlf = warn`

Comment: *"When rebase prompts for the commands, specify edit for each one."* - In my case, it was only necessary to specify `edit` for the one which needed to be fixed. I think it will be for you as well - which will hopefully give you the easier/less tedious way you're looking for.